# Use files from one Java project in another project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, reference, hyperlink, include

I have two Java projects -   `MyProject`   and   `MyProjectStubs`

The `MyProject` has the bulk of the classes for the effort.

The `MyProjectStubs` has certain "dummy" classes whose processing will be replaced later by more sensitive processing - which cannot be stored on the same network as the `MyProject` project.

I was able to tell `MyProjectStubs` to "require" `MyProject` in order to build.  But of course, I have to have the same files that are in `MyProjectStubs` also in `MyProject`, so that `MyProject` will build without error.

Is there a way to remove those dummy files from `MyProject`, and have `MyProject` reference the files in `MyProjectStubs` without creating a circular reference between the two projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interfaces. That's exactly what "dummy" files are, if you put interfaces to the classes you will develop in the future in MyProject, then implement these interface stubs in the other `MyProjectStubs`, `MyProject` will compile.

This is one of the main reasons interfaces exist.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense - but like I have a static init() method in the class that the main project calls.  I can't put static methods in an interface.

One suggestion someone had was to make a JAR of the stubs and include the JAR as an external library in the MyProject project.

Comment: You could refactor that `init()` method into two different classes. I didn't say this would be easy or quick, but it would work, and it would solve your problem. In my opinion this solution is cleaner because you can finish the MyProject jar and be done with it, rather than slowly migrating classes over as they get written. [Read this thread](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/why-would-a-programmer-want-to-separate-implementation-from-interface)